# Recording UIAutomation events in Instruments: get numeric instead of string value

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

when capturing events in the Automation event editor of Instruments (with the neat record button blow the editor), I often get responses like this:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Filter"].tap();
```

After capturing, I have the option to set the captured event to equivalent code visually.

[image]

Question: is there a way to set the captured events to the generic/numeric-value instead of the string-value by default? I know I can change each of them by hand, but usually I would like to have the

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[2].tap();
```

value, rather than this way

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Filter"].tap();
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Apples technical support - there is no such possibility in Instruments yet.